# normalize-space() not working

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

There is xslt code for version 1.0 but I want to convert it to version 2.0.

```
 <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(round((. - $var1) div $var2))"/>
```

But when I try to run it, the SAXON output is:

```
F [Saxon-HE 9.5.0.2] XPTY0004: Required item type of first argument of normalize-space() is xs:string; supplied value has item type numeric
```

help me in finding and solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: XSLT 2.0 has a high level of backwards compatibility with XSLT 1.0, until you present it with code that is nonsense. Applying normalize-space to a number makes no sense at all, so get rid of it.

Comment: What did you expect using normalize-space on a number?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message mentions, `normalize-space` expects a string as an argument, but `round` returns a numeric value. Numbers don't actually have spaces in though, so there is no need to use `normalize-space` on the result.

This should work instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="round((. - $var1) div $var2)"/>
```